# jquery push to make multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, arrays, push, multidimensional-array

I've looked at other similar posts with no help, they all start with a multidimensional array already made, I want to magically make one by using .push.

My array:

```
ItemsArray.push({ 
                   RoomName : RoomName, 
                   Item : {//this is where I want the multi-array } 
               });
```

I tried using: `ItemsArray.Item.push{ stuff:morestuff }` but it stopped saying 'ItemsArray.Item' is not defined... which is clearly ridiculous ?

Also tried: `ItemsArray[1].push{}` with same error...

Surely this must be a stupid simple problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are creating Item as an object. You want it to be an array to be able to push into it.

```
var ItemArray = [];
ItemArray.push({
    RoomName : 'RoomName', 
    Item : []
});

ItemArray[0].Item.push("New Item");

console.log(ItemArray);
```

[Here](http://www.karmagination.com/blog/2009/07/29/javascript-kung-fu-object-array-and-literals/) is a good blog post that has in-depth detail about the difference between objects and arrays.

Answer (score 7):

```
var tdarray = [[]];
tdarray[0].push(22);
tdarray[0].push(23);
alert(tdarray[0][1]); //you can change this
```