# make multidimensional array jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
<tr class="" style="display: table-row;">
    <td id="" name="">id</td>
    <td id="" name="">name</td>
    <td id="">hobbies</td>
    <td id="">age</td>
    <td id="">gender</td>
</tr>
<tr class="" style="display: table-row;">
    <td id="" name="">015-08-0003-000-04</td>
    <td id="" name="">john</td>
    <td id=""><span id="sports" class="" title="">basketball</span>,<span id="music" class="" title="">guitar</span></td>
    <td id="">21</td>
    <td id="">male</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="af_arpta_propertybuilding_addlandref">Add</a></td>
</tr>
```

This is my table for getting personal information(dynamic table).
I want to create an array out of this data.
I created a single array out of this like this

```
var $rows2 = $('#tableid').find("tr:not(:eq(0))");
$rows2.each(function () {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td');
    var id = $tds.eq(0).text();
    var name = $tds.eq(1).text();
    var hoobies = $tds.eq(2).text();
    var age = $tds.eq(3).text();
    var gender = $tds.eq(4).text();

    perinfo.push({
        id: id,
        name: name,
        age: age,
        gender: gender

    });
```

My problem is how to get the hobbies i want to create another entry after gender named hobbies but this time it will be multidimensional to cover sports and music category.  Any suggestion to create that array out of this one.

I am hoping it would look like

```
[{
    "id": "015-08-0003-000-04",
    "name": "john",
    "age": "21",
    "gender": "male"
    "hobbies": [{
        "sport": "basketball",
        "music": "guitar"
    }]
}]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/w2znoj4k/2/)

Comment: JQuery can handle multidimensional array. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075082/jquery-push-to-make-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an array of hobbies yourself, `text()` will return a concatenated string of text content.

You can use [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map) to create an array of object from a given set of elements.

Also, from the given markup, I assume that there can be multiple `tr` elements, in that case you should not use `id` for the hobby `span` elements, as ID of an element must be unique.

```js
var perinfo = $('#tableid tr').slice(1).map(function () {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td');
    var id = $tds.eq(0).text();
    var name = $tds.eq(1).text();
    var hoobies = $tds.eq(2).find('span').map(function () {
        var obj = {};
        obj[$(this).data('id')] = $(this).text();
        return obj;
    }).get();
    var age = $tds.eq(3).text();
    var gender = $tds.eq(4).text();

    return {
        id: id,
        name: name,
        age: age,
        gender: gender,
        hoobies: hoobies
    };
}).get();
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(perinfo));
console.log(perinfo)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tableid'>
    <tr class="" style="display: table-row;">
        <td id="" name="">id</td>
        <td id="" name="">name</td>
        <td id="">hobbies</td>
        <td id="">age</td>
        <td id="">gender</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" style="display: table-row;">
        <td id="" name="">015-08-0003-000-04</td>
        <td id="" name="">john</td>
        <td id="">
            <span data-id="sports" class="" title="">basketball</span>,
            <span data-id="music" class="" title="">guitar</span>
        </td>
        <td id="">21</td>
        <td id="">male</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yeah there will be multiple row yeah i think i will use class for this let me work for a couple of minutes be right back

Comment: if i put `data-class` will it function same like `class` or do i need to declare each one?havent used `data-class or data-id`

Comment: no... class and data-class are different... you can assign a class for css else you can use a attribute css rule for styling

Comment: I have a doubt about your object format... the `hoobies` is an array or an object?

Comment: You might want http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nkufLp74/2/ - check the value of `hobbies`

Comment: i check the earlier version of the fiddle you created i think i can work with that one i am more familiar with that format than any other format available\

Comment: @BrownmanRevival If you want to use a class also then you can also try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nkufLp74/4/

Comment: @BrownmanRevival in that case a more appropriate format will be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nkufLp74/5/

Comment: @BrownmanRevival regarding `data-id`, you can give an name after `data-`

Comment: i see so i can give any name after `data-` and call it anytime. like calling `attr('')`?

Comment: @BrownmanRevival Yes, it is part of the [data api](http://api.jquery.com/data/) - also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: great help..much appreciated happy coding